# Array with random unique integer numbers (0 to array.length - 1)

Tags: javascript, arrays

This question is how to generate an array of all unique fixed integer numbers that the highest is equal to the length - 1 of the array.

**An example of a result array:**
[3, 6, 4, 2, 1, 5, 0]

- All unique
- Random
- Highest number is in the highest number of the index (6)

**This one is not:**
[3, 16, 4, 22, 19039, 555, 0]

Comment: Can you please count elements in your "right" array and tell us the result?

Comment: simply you are asking for an array from 1 to array length

Comment: @MUHAMMADILYAS yes but numbers need to be spread in random order as symlink's answer.

Answer (score 1):

First populate a sequential array, then sort by returning a random result in the compareFunction.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```js
let arrLen = 7, resArr = []
for(let i=0; i < arrLen; i++){
  resArr.push(i)
}

resArr.sort((a,b) => {
  let ranBool = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
  //returns 0 or -1, which either leaves the integers in place or sorts the second one before the first 
  return ranBool - 1
})

console.log(resArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

- In my solution we create an array of numbers in order [1, 2, 3] call arrayOfNumbers
- We then create an empty array call randomArray
- We forEach loop through the array we created in first step
- We generate a random number base on the length of the array and decreasing it throughout the forEach loop
- We then push a random number from the arrayOfNumbers to randomArray
- At the same time (loop) after pushing a random number from arrayOfNumbers we use array methods splice to remove it from arrayOfNumbers (so we can't longer use it)
- We short the length by one so we can only generate random number in the length of the arrayOfNumbers array. So next time we call arrayOfNumbers[random] we'll have a unique number from this array.

```js
   function randomNumbers(howMany) {
  arrayOfNumbers = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
    arrayOfNumbers.push(i);
  };

  const arr = [...arrayOfNumbers];
  let length = arr.length
  const randomArr = [];

  arr.forEach((num, i) => {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);

    randomArr.push(arrayOfNumbers[random]);
    arrayOfNumbers.splice(arrayOfNumbers.indexOf(arrayOfNumbers[random]), 1);
    length--

  });

  return randomArr;
};

console.log(randomNumbers(101));
```